# Image processing batch tool to resample images with YCbCr=4:4:4

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, image-processing, image-manipulation

I am looking for lightweight image processing tool that will resize images to JPEG in YCbCr = 4:4:4, that is, no chromatic subsampling. I am using this to generate square thumbnails.

I need 4:4:4 because I am not sure about the quality of 4.2.2 or 4.1.1 as they will have greater amount of artifacts, which will affect the quality of my thumbnails.

It will be run from a web server (ASP.Net MVC 3). Command-line tool, standalone application and libraries are all acceptable since it will run in separate processes anyway.

Anything out there except ImageMagick? I think it is too bulky.

Thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: when you say you want to make them square, are you really resampling, or just cropping the longer side?  If so, it's possible to crop losslessly.  I think you might have to be a factor of 8 on the top or left side -- because you do it at the cell level.

Comment: http://imageresizing.net/ - It's an ASP.NET library that wraps both FreeImage and WIC, both of which allow you to set the subsampling quality. Turns your job into a 1-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows Imaging Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows you to choose your own JPEG chroma subsampling option. See [Encoder Options: JPEG Codec specific options: JpegYCrCbSubsampling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719871(v=VS.85).aspx#encoderoptions)

This is a very heavy-handed approach and requires a somewhat difficult learning curve. You may want to look for other options before delving into WIC.

Answer (score 0):

IrfanView has an option to remove color subsampling. In JPEG save dialog, check "Disable color subsampling". This should store the JPEG with all channels in full resolution.

However, looking at its command-line option manual, I don't find any mention of this option. So, it may not be possible to automate or programmatically use this function.